# Angular2 directive, mouse movement event

Tags: angular

I want to know how I can trigger a directive function when moving or clicking the mouse on some object.

I found this part of code which I think will do what I want. I am not sure about the syntax and what is actually happening though.

As part of the directive class I have this:

```
mousedown = new EventEmitter();
@HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
onMousedown(event) { 
    console.log(event); 
    this.mousedown.emit(event); 
}
```

Which, if I am clicking the div that has the directive, is printing the event to the console as expected. Although I am not sure on how the second line, `this.mousedown.emit()` is used.

What is actually called with the `.emit()` function?

Answer (score 1):

`mousedown = new EventEmitter();` seems redundant for your use case. If you prepend  an `@Output()` annotation than you would listen to an `mousedown` event and immediately emit another one.

**update**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[clickToOtherEvent]'
})
class EventTranslator {
  @Output() otherEvent = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  onMousedown(event) { 
    console.log(event); 
    this.otherEvent.emit(event); 
  }
}
```

You can use the directive like

```
<button clickToOtherEvent (otherEvent)="doSomething()">test output</button>
```

The directive listens to `mousedown` event and emits an `otherEvent` you can again listen to.

Comment: I'm not sure how, can you submit an example of the Output decorator?

Comment: So I can't really get this into my head, is otherEvent a function that I have to implement, which is called when .emit is invoked?

Comment: I just tried to elaborate a bit more on the `EventEmitter` line the code in your question contains. You don't need this line at all when you just want to listen to the `mousedown` event and act on it. The `@Output() ...` line is a custom event. Components that use your directive can listen to that event. What the code in my answer does is listen to the `mousedown` event and in `onMouseDown` it fires an `otherEvent` for each incoming `mousedown` event. The HTML example line listens to this event can calls `doSomething()` when it is fired from the `clickToOtherEvent` directive.